# Swift Custom Cell doesn't instantiate a Label in it!! Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, cell

I have a tableView containing multiple cells which i can select but it doesn't display the label.text in it.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ShowDeviceCell{
           
            cell.setEntry(deviceName: devices_names[indexPath.row])
            
            return cell
        }
        let cell = ShowDeviceCell()
        
        cell.setEntry(deviceName: devices_names[indexPath.row])
        
            
        return  cell
    }
```

And this is my cell definition:

```
class ShowDeviceCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var deviceCell: UILabel! = {
        let lbl = UILabel()
         lbl.textColor = .black
         lbl.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
         lbl.textAlignment = .left
         return lbl
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
       // addSubview(deviceCell)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    func setEntry (deviceName : String){
        if let cellLabel = self.deviceCell{
            cellLabel.text = deviceName
        }
        
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

The error is the same whenever i try to use cell.deviceCell i got this error **Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `if let` expression in `cellForRow` is nonsensical. Force downcast the cell. If it crashes it reveals a **design** mistake. And what is the initializer in the outlet for? If it’s supposed to be an outlet make the settings in Interface Builder.

Comment: Since it doesn't work, i'm testing different things. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It worked, i have removed the register and the init methods. And by adding the right identifier of the cell in the storyboard. Thank you for your help.